# Lua socket for scrap mechanic

Tags: sockets, unity-game-engine, lua

I'm trying to add a socket connection to gather realtime player data from the game to use in a python app, and i got all the python server side working fine...

But i can't seem to even do a `require("socket")` call from any of the lua files in the game, does anyone knows how can i do that to make it work, or what file to edit?

Already tried the standard lua socket call but it doesn't goes pass the `require` line, and don't know why but i can not see the console in the game so can't even debug it

```
local host, port = "127.0.0.1", 100
local socket = require("socket")
local tcp = assert(socket.tcp())

tcp:connect(host, port);
tcp:send("hello world");
local s, status, partial = tcp:receive()
tcp:close()
```

Comment: if you cannot get error messages into a console or log file you have some serious design problem in your game, which you should fix befor you attempt any socket communiation. I'm sure this is somehow covered by the Unity party. if not you should catch the error and wirte it to a file.
make sure your socket module is located in package.path

Comment: @Piglet it's not my game, i just want to add some functionality to it